# Making a list of mouse over event functions in Tkinter

Tags: python, list, user-interface, tkinter, mouseover

I'm making a GUI for a medical tool as a class project. Given a condition, it should output a bunch of treatment options gathered from different websites like webMD. I would like to be able to handle mouseover events on any of the treatments listed to give a little more information about the treatment (such as the category of drug, whether it is a generic or not, etc).

The labels are stored in a list, as I have no idea how many different treatments will be returned beforehand. So my question is how can I make these mouseover events work. I can't write a function definition for every single possible label, they would number in the hundreds or thousands. I'm sure there's a very pythonic way to do it, but I have no idea what.

Here's my code for creating the labels:

```
    def search_click():
        """
        Builds the search results after the search button has been clicked
        """
        self.output_frame.destroy()                                                 # Delete old results
        build_output()                                                              # Rebuild output frames
        treament_list = mockUpScript.queryConditions(self.condition_entry.get())    # Get treatment data
        labels = []
        frames = [self.onceFrame, self.twiceFrame, self.threeFrame, self.fourFrame] # holds the list of frames
        for treament in treament_list:                                              # For each treatment in the list
            label = ttk.Label(frames[treament[1] - 1], text=treament[0])            # Build the label for treatment

            labels.append(label)                                                    # Add the treatment to the list
            label.pack()
```

and here is what the GUI looks like (don't judge [-; )[image: GUI image]

The text "Hover over drugs for information" should be changed depending on which drug your mouse is hovering over.

Comment: I don't understand your code, you named the function `search_click` but it seems you are asking about mouseover code? Nor have you given any indication as to where and what the actual mouseover text should be - do you want just the name of the item? or is this pulling from a file?

Comment: Yes the function search_click is run when someone clicks the search button, so none of the drugs would show up before it's clicked. Therefore anything to do with mouseover events would have to occur after this. I mainly included this code so people would understand how the labels are being created. In the end this information would likely come from another file, but for now I would be happy with just the name of the drug so I understand how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can't write a function definition for every single possible label, they would number in the hundreds or thousands. I'm sure there's a very pythonic way to do it, but I have no idea what.

Check out [lambda functions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk) which are nearly identical to what you want.

In your case, something like:

```
def update_bottom_scroll_bar(text):
    # whatever you want to do to update the text at the bottom

for treatment in treament_list:  # For each treatment in the list
    label = ttk.Label(frames[treatment[1] - 1], text=treatment[0])  # Build the label for treatment

    label.bind("<Enter>", lambda event, t=treatment: update_bottom_scroll_bar(text=t))
    label.bind("<Leave>", lambda event: update_bottom_scroll_bar(text='Default label text'))

    labels.append(label)  # Add the treatment to the list
    label.pack()
```

Also please spell your variables right, I corrected `treament` to `treatment`...

Comment: Oops, the one downside of code completion, perpetuating typos xD